# React Testing Library: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm using react testing library for running tests inside a react application.
I've installed the library [compress.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress.js) which imports the following module `import "regenerator-runtime/runtime.js";` inside `node_modules/compress.js/src/index.js`

When running `react-scripts test` I receive the following error:

```
....\node_modules\compress.js\src\index.js:2
    import "regenerator-runtime/runtime.js";

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I'm using the following version for testing-library:

```
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
"@testing-library/react": "^8.0.4",
```

Is there a way to enable ES Modules imports?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm running into the same issue with this package in particular